# C++ EOF namespace

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, std, eof

So, for curiosity, how come EOF doens't have a namespace defined?
Why not **::EOF** or **std ::EOF**?

```
#include <cstdio>

while (std::scanf("%s", someStr) != ::EOF); // nope
while (std::scanf("%s", someStr) != std::EOF); // nope
while (std::scanf("%s", someStr) != EOF); // here we go
```

Comment: scanf() and EOF are from the standard C library, which precede both C++ and C++ namespaces. "EOF" is implemented as a int macro definition.

Comment: @FoggyDay And now you should explain why `scanf` does have a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

`EOF` is a preprocessor macro defined in `<cstdio>` (and in the C header `<stdio.h>` which is also usable from C++).

Preprocessor macros do text substitution on source code, before that code is actually compiled.    As such, preprocessor macros are not names that can appear in any namespace.

This is different from function names declared in headers which can appear in namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

In C, EOF was defined as a *macro*, using `#define`. It could possibly have been defined as `const`, except that it predates `const`.

For compatibility, this means it's also defined as a macro in C++. Something like:

```
#define EOF -1
```

If you know how `#define` works, you should see why `::EOF` and `std::EOF` produce compiler errors. `#define`'d macros are simple textual substitutions, so `::EOF` expands to `::-1` and `std::EOF` expands to `std::-1`, which are both invalid.